# multiple effects on one element simultaneously

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fadeIn and and animate simultaneously. However it is doing them one after the other. How do you do it at the same time.

I have tried:

```
$('#box').fadeIn(1000);
$('#box').animate({marginTop:'0'}, 1000);
```

AND

```
$('#box').fadeIn(1000).animate({marginTop:'0'}, 1000);
```

But they both do the same thing. One event then another. How do I do them at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could animate opacity instead of FadeIn. So set the element to opacity 0, remove display:none, and then animate the opacity, it will happen the same time as the margin animation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `dequeue`:

> When jQuery.dequeue() is called, the next function on the queue is removed from the queue, and then executed.

This will cause them both to happen simultaneously.

```
$('#box').fadeIn(1000).dequeue().animate({marginTop:'0'}, 1000);
```

Comment: That worked, except before the fadein I have delay(), and dequeue seems to ignore the delay